# bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline' for "&! "

Tags: macos, terminal, syntax

I have the following `script.sh` running in `zsh`. But since I am running the script as `sudo` user used shell differs between each other.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $SHELL
nohup geth --syncmode fast --cache=1024 > geth_server.out 2>&1 &!
```

Output in `macOS`:

```
$ chmod +x script.sh
$ sudo ./script.sh
/bin/sh
syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
```

which generated following error on macOS but works fine in `linux`: `syntax error near unexpected token` newline'`

---

Output in `linux`:

```
$ chmod +x script.sh
$ sudo ./script.sh
/bin/bash
# works fine
```

---

The error seems like generated due to `!` at the end of the line. Is there anyway to fix this, what may be the reason for this? Exact same script works fine in linux environment

Comment: What are you expecting `&!` to do? As far as I know, that's not meaningful in bash (although in zsh, it runs a command in the background and disowns it).

Comment: I was using `!` as a trick when ssh connection is disconnected it keeps the process keep running on the background

Comment: This sounds like you're running Bash, but try to use a Zsh feature.

Comment: I am using Zsh but on macOS, that's why I am confused @BenjaminW.

Comment: It's not a problem of macOS vs. Linux, it's about the difference between Zsh (has `&!`) and Bash (does not have `&!`).

Comment: Ah I am in zsh, but in my script file #!/bin/bash is top of the file and since I am running it as sudo , /bin/sh shell is taken place; but in linux the error is not catched and it works all fine, but still it works if the shell is `/bin/bash` instead of `/bin/sh`

Comment: @alper If you want the script to run in zsh (so you can use zsh features, like `&!`), then set the shebang line to `#!/bin/zsh` instead of either `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/bin/sh`.

Comment: That's a option but in case script is running under `#!/bin/sh` (if sudo runs it), can I make it detect the shell run the nohup line without `!`

Comment: @GordonDavisson Please see my updated question. Like in macOS it give the error when shell is `/bin/sh` but it works fine in linux even the shell is `/bin/bash`

Comment: `echo $SHELL` tells you what your user shell is, not what shell is actually running the script; it's irrelevant here. The actual difference seems to be the version of bash being used -- macOS has an old version (3.2.57), which will give an error, but newer versions don't. I don't know why newer versions don't give an error, since as far as I can see it's still not valid bash syntax. So don't use it, just use `&`.